# Playframework 2.3.4 gzip not working

Tags: java, gzip, playframework-2.3

I have enabled Gzip encoding for Play Framework 2.3.4, according to the documentation https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/GzipEncoding:

I have added the dependency in build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += filters
```

Then I have created the Global object:

```
import play.GlobalSettings;
import play.api.mvc.EssentialFilter;
import play.filters.gzip.GzipFilter;

public class Global extends GlobalSettings {
    public <T extends EssentialFilter> Class<T>[] filters() {
        return new Class[]{GzipFilter.class};
    }
}
```

I made a test by calling:

```
curl -I -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' http://localhost:9000/my-api
```

The result was:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 3202
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

But I was expecting to find the following header in the answer:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Somebody else had the same problem ? Did I miss something in the configuration?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is the -I option; that is only returning the headers, so there is no content to zip.

If I use -v, I see the "Content-Encoding: gzip" in the response.

```
curl -v -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' http://localhost:9000/my-api
```